# Pass parameter in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a closure function in javascript and that i just want to call on addEventListener. I am not using ES6 so that i can not use static method with class.

```js
 function validationFunction()
    {
        let _validateAlphaNumeric = function (param1)
        {
            return /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/.test(param1);
        }

        let _customValidation = function (param1,param2){
            let a = new RegExp(param2);
            return a.test(param1);
        }
        return {
            ValidateAlphaNumeric : _validateAlphaNumeric,
            CustomValidation :_customValidation
        }
    }

    
    function valid(){
        var validation = new validationFunction();
        if(validation.ValidateAlphaNumeric(document.getElementById("Name").value)){
            document.getElementById("ErrorName").innerHTML = "Alpha numeric";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("ErrorName").innerHTML = "Some error";
        }

        if(validation.CustomValidation(document.getElementById("Name").value,"[A-Za-z]{3}"))
        {
            document.getElementById("ErrorName1").innerHTML = "True";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("ErrorName1").innerHTML = "False";
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="valid();">
<br>
<input type="text" id="Name">
<br>
<span id="ErrorName" style="color:red"></span>
<br>
<span id="ErrorName1" style="color:red"></span>
```

This works fine for me, problem came when i am trying to this function using addEventListener. I know that i can use pattern attribute in html5 for validation, but its not about validation i have to do some more stuff onkeypress. I do not want to make another method for it.

Comment: Please ignore let keyword from it. 

var valid = new validationFunction();
    var name = document.getElementById("Name");
    name.addEventListener('keypress',valid.ValidateAlphaNumeric, false);

I am trying to make this type of code but i do not know where i am making an mistake.

Comment: Specifically *what* problem are you getting?

Comment: not able to call closure function which have parameter in addEventListener.

Comment: Where's that class? Is `validationFunction` a constructor?

Comment: @zer00ne : function is class in javascript..

Comment: I don't quite understand you question, but yes - you can pass parameters to event listeners. Just use `.bind(...)` or `.apply(...)`.

Comment: @PramodThakur if  `validationFumction` is a  function constructor, you should have set some properties/methods with `this`. BTW function is a *first class* object in JavaScript.

Comment: @zer00ne : if i am using this keyword then i need to create an object every time for initializing this. i dont want to do that.. You can see that alphanumeric method has a parameter and that parameter i want to pass as dynamic while calling that method..